# Custom Property Drawer not saving content when hitting Play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a custom property drawer for a grid base class that will be used as default for further inheriting classes down the line.

here are the scripts I'm using

```
using UnityEditor;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(CustomGrid<Tile>))]
public class GridPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    private int yLength = -1;
    private int xLength = -1;
    private CustomGrid<Tile> grid;

    private float padding = 5;

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        grid = fieldInfo.GetValue(property.serializedObject.targetObject) as CustomGrid<Tile>;

        if (grid.Tiles == null || (grid.XLength == 0 && grid.YLength == 0)) grid = null;

        if (xLength < 0)
        {
            if (grid == null) xLength = 0;
            else xLength = grid.XLength;
        }
        if (yLength < 0)
        {
            if (grid == null) yLength = 0;
            else yLength = grid.YLength;
        }

        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        property.isExpanded = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(property.isExpanded, "Grid");

        if (property.isExpanded)
        {
            EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

            //padding = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Padding", padding);

            yLength = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Row(s)", yLength);
            xLength = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Column(s)", xLength);

            GUILayout.Space(10);

            if (grid == null || (grid.XLength == 0 && grid.YLength == 0))
            {
                if (yLength != 0 && xLength != 0)
                {
                    if (GUILayout.Button("Create Grid"))
                    {
                        grid = new CustomGrid<Tile>(xLength, yLength);
                        fieldInfo.SetValue(property.serializedObject.targetObject, grid);
                        EditorUtility.SetDirty(property.serializedObject.targetObject);
                        UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                float inspectorWidth = EditorGUIUtility.currentViewWidth;
                float tileWidth = Mathf.Clamp((inspectorWidth / grid.XLength) - padding, 5, 40);
                float tileHeight = tileWidth; // Make the tile square

                EditorGUI.indentLevel--;

                for (int y = 0; y < grid.YLength; y++)
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

                    GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

                    for (int x = 0; x < grid.XLength; x++)
                    {
                        GUI.color = grid.Tiles[x, y].IsAvailable ? Color.white : Color.gray;

                        if (GUILayout.Button("", GUILayout.Width(tileWidth), GUILayout.Height(tileHeight)))
                        {
                            grid.Tiles[x, y].ToggleAvailability();
                            fieldInfo.SetValue(property.serializedObject.targetObject, grid);
                            EditorUtility.SetDirty(property.serializedObject.targetObject);
                            UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
                        }

                        GUI.color = Color.white;
                    }

                    GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

                    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                }

                EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

                if (yLength != grid.YLength || xLength != grid.XLength)
                {
                    GUILayout.Space(10);

                    if (GUILayout.Button("Update grid"))
                    {
                        grid = new CustomGrid<Tile>(xLength, yLength);
                        fieldInfo.SetValue(property.serializedObject.targetObject, grid);
                        EditorUtility.SetDirty(property.serializedObject.targetObject);
                        UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
                    }
                }
            }

            EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        }

        property.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}
```

Here are the custom grid class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class CustomGrid<T> where T : Tile
{
    public T[,] Tiles { get; private set; }

    public int XLength { get; private set; }
    public int YLength { get; private set; }

    public CustomGrid(int xLength, int yLength)
    {
        Tiles = new T[xLength, yLength];

        for (int x = 0; x < xLength; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < yLength; y++)
            {
                Tiles[x, y] = new Tile(x, y) as T;
            }
        }

        XLength = xLength;
        YLength = yLength;
    }

    public List<T> GetNeighbouringTilesFromTile(T tile)
    {
        List<T> neighbours = new List<T>();

        if (tile.X > 0) neighbours.Add(Tiles[tile.X - 1, tile.Y]);
        if (tile.X < XLength - 1) neighbours.Add(Tiles[tile.X + 1, tile.Y]);
        if (tile.Y > 0) neighbours.Add(Tiles[tile.X, tile.Y - 1]);
        if (tile.Y < YLength - 1) neighbours.Add(Tiles[tile.X, tile.Y + 1]);

        return neighbours;
    }
}
```

and base tile class scripts

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Tile
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public Tile()
    {
        // need to parse position in grid manually
    }

    public Tile(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public bool IsAvailable { get; private set; } = true;

    public void ToggleAvailability()
    {
        IsAvailable = !IsAvailable;
    }
}
```

And then I'm just using a basic monobehaviour script as an anchor for my custom type to see it in the inspector

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Playground : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CustomGrid<Tile> grid;
}
```

Any help in the matter would be greatly appreciated, thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unity cannot serialize multi-demensional arrays.

You can make a class that represents the data, then a class that represents an array of that data, and then in the grid class use an array of that array class.  eg.

```
class Data { x, y }
class DataArray { Data[] }
class Grid { DataArray[] }
```

or use the serialization callbacks using [ISerializationCallbackReceiver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html)

Generics aren't (or weren't) serializable either (not mentioned in the serialization page, so this may have changed).
For that make a concrete class

```
class Generic<T> {}
class GenericData : Generic<Data> {}
```

From Docs [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html):

> Note: Unity doesn’t support serialization of multilevel types (multidimensional arrays, jagged arrays, dictionaries, and nested container types). If you want to serialize these, you have two options:

1. Wrap the nested type in a class or struct
2. Use serialization callbacks, by implementing ISerializationCallbackReceiver, to perform custom serialization.